# Dispose IInputStream

Tags: c#, uwp, idisposable

when I use object of  `StreamSocket` and return property IInputStream or `IOutputStream` into clients code.These interfaces inherit from `IDisposable`. And when  calling `Dispose` method, i expect what instance of `StreamSocket` will be disposed. But nothing happens, nay TCP connection not closing.What does do `Dispose` method when object cast to one of this interfaces? Thank you.

Comment: GC is non deterministic, so it may not get disposed of straight away. Secondly, we have no idea how you call dispose, so it maybe that the method isn't even being called....

Comment: how do you know the connection is not closing?

Answer (score 0):

Dispose flags the object as available for garbage collection. Unless the author of the object called close on the stream from the Dispose method, you may or may not see the stream closed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Wait wait wait. You get IInputStream and IOutputStream. *Why* are you expecting that calling Dispose on these objects that you got from properties should close StreamSocket connection? Call Dispose on StreamSocket object itself.
([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.aspx))

Comment: I bet that calling dispose on streams enforces flushing for these streams and closing them. But I'm not sure that you can't re-utilize the same connection afterwards.

Comment: Ok. What does do Dispose method when object of StreamSocket cast to one of this interfaces?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand you. StreamSocket _can not_ be casted to IInputStream or IOutputStream because StreamSocket class does not implement these iterfaces.
`streamSocketObject is IInputStream` -> always `false`
`streamSocketObject is IOutputStream` -> always `false`

As far as I can see, the only interfaces you may cast object of StreamSocket type to are `IDisposable`, `IStreamSocket`, `IStreamSocket2`.

And ofc calling Dispose on IDisposable disposes of the disposable StreamSocket (and closes the connection).